# PhantomJS and session timeout

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying to scrape with phantomJS and selenium (and scrapy) into a list of links inside a website. I'm new to PhantomJS and Selenium so I'll ask here.
I think the website has a session timeout because I can scrape just the first of those links. Then I get this error:

> NoSuchWindowException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Currently Window
>   handle/name is invalid
>   (closed?)","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"460","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:33038","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"url\":

That's part of my code:

```
    class bllanguage(scrapy.Spider):
        handle_httpstatus_list = [302]
        name = "bllanguage"
        download_delay = 1
        allowed_domains = ["http://explore.com/"]
        f = open("link")
        start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
        f.close()

        def __init__(self):
            self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/phantomjs')

        def start_requests(self):
        for u in self.start_urls:
            r = scrapy.Request(url = u, dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse)
            r.meta['dont_redirect'] = True
            yield r

        def parse(self, response):
            self.driver.get(response.url)
            #print response.url
            search_field = []
```

Etc.

The session timeout problem is just my interpretation, I've seen other messages like that but none of them has a solution. What I would like to try is to "close" the request to each link inside the "link" file. I don't know if this is something PhantomJS does naturally or I have to insert something: I've seen there's a `resourceTimeout` setting. Is it the right thing to use and where can I put it inside my code?